# Suddenly a strange border exists around selected text in word and powerpoint (microsoft)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft

There's a fluorescent blue box around text I select. It happens in both Word (only text inside tables) and PowerPoint.

I never changed any settings and it just happened suddenly one day...

[image: a picture of the issue]

Does anyone know why this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: I Guess you updated office?

Comment: Could you tell us the version of Word and Powerpoint where you are experiencing this?

Comment: Seems like a text box. Have you created table yourself, or copied from somewhere else?

Comment: Check the option for display of text boundaries. http://addbalance.com/word/textBoundaries.htm

Comment: @jhon no I havent updated office

Comment: @moragHughson
I have the word 2010 and powerpoint 2010.

Comment: @MátéJuhász 
It's not a textbook. It's just a new ppt document in powerpoint and I simply typed in a dummy text, and highlighted it to show an example of what happens.

Comment: I have the same versions of Word and PowerPoint, and it seems I too have the same blue border. I had not noticed it before suggesting that it was not that way before. I suspect a Windows change rather than an application setting, but have not found it. It is not the narrator though, as many google search results seemed to suggest it was. Sorry not to be more help. If I find anything will post more.